# Why does Facebook auth redirect cause server error?

Tags: facebook, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

I have built a simple url shortening app in codeigniter that also allows users to login via facebook.

When authorizing for the first time it returns a server error after allowing permissions on facebook.

I've narrowed the problem down to either my routes file or my htaccess. But i cannot get it work no matter what i try.

As the app is a url shortner, any routes that are not specified resort to a default route. Like so...

```
$route['login'] = "auth/login";
$route['about'] = "pages/about";
$route['(:any)'] = "redirect/index/$1";
```

Which i think is why it's failing to auth. I tried to do:

```
$route['auth_social/(:any)'] = "auth_social/$1";
```

which didnt work either. The only time i can get it to work is if i change my .htaccess to

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|table-images|js|robots\.txt|css|captcha)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

but then my url shortening breaks and will not work. It's driving me crazy.

Can anybody see where I am going wrong here?

Here is my full .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

```
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

EDIT:

Here is the error from the server logs:

```
 [10-Jan-2013 11:02:25 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
  thrown in /Users/mycomputer/Documents/grpe/app/application/libraries/facebook/base_facebook.php on line 1058
```

Comment: What’s the _actual_ error message? (Check your server’s logfiles!)

Comment: ok. i'm using mamp on osx. how do i find my logfiles?

Comment: That’s what I thought – just an uncaught exception while using the PHP SDK. So most likely it is not connected to your routing, but to your application logic.

Comment: ok, but when i change my htaccess file it does work, but breaks the shorten part. What do you suggest?

Comment: Could be a problem with the cookie path – if the SDK does not get the cookie value it needs because it is not valid under the current HTTP path, that might explain why it fails with your routing and not otherwise.

Comment: ok, so can an exception be added to the routes or htaccess that will allow it / not block it?

Answer (score 0):

What oAuth library are you using?

I'd strongly recommend using this oAuth2 sparks library:
http://getsparks.org/packages/oauth2/versions/HEAD/show

I've been using it for a while now without any problem at all for login/signup.

HTH

Comment: Thanks. i was using a modified version of tank auth.